# C/C++: Acces single character from a pointer character single-dimension array

Tags: c++, c

From an initialized Pointer to Array of Characters like this:

```
char *someChar[]={"Some","Text","Here"};
```

How would I be able to call for instance, the letter x of "Text", I can't move it's address `someChar[1]` to some offset to acces x, since this is not a 2-dimensional array.

Using `*someChar[1][2]` gives the Invalid Indirection Error.
The code is as simple as this: http://ideone.com/OdvocT

Comment: This won't compile anymore. You can't initialise a `char*` from a string literal.

Comment: Did any one says to use `*someChar[1][2]` ?

Comment: Read up on arrays and pointers in C/C++, e.g. [here](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be `someChar[1][2]`.

`someChar[1]` is the second array element, which is a pointer to the first letter of `"Text"`.

Comment: Gives Invalid Indirection Error

Comment: Where is indirection operator in this answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can access it as `someChar[1][2]`. In case of an array of pointers to `char`, the first dimension of array element is for string and the second is for choosing character in that string.

Comment: Gives Invalid Indirection Error

Comment: What you did actually?

Comment: Do you think `*someChar[1][2]` and `someChar[1][2]` is [same](http://ideone.com/5JvKIw)?

Comment: @Yawz: Then your code isn't the same as what you claim, or what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

In C (I have no idea how this all works in C++)

```
char *someChar[]={"Some","Text","Here"};
```

is an array of pointers. Each element is a pointer.

`someChar[1]` is a pointer. It points to a `char`

`*(someChar[1])` is a `char`, the `'T'` (also accessible as `someChar[1][0]`).
`*(someChar[1] + 2)` is a `char`, the `'x'` (also accessible as `someChar[1][2]`).

Comment: Gives Invalid Indirection Error

Comment: @Yawz: that must be a particularity of C++. I don't know C++; my answer pertains to C (note added to the answer itself).

Answer (score 0):

```
for every someChar+i{
    for every *(someChar+i){
        code you logic here
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `someChar[i]`, it is *exactly equivalent* to `*(someChar + 1)`.

Comment: it's a mistake, i ment he should browse 
    j = 0
    for every (someChar+i)+j

Comment: It would be nice if you explain this code as well. Code only answers are not welcomed at SO.